# MariaDB root login problem. (can login but, not security)

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.5

I have some problem.

Install MariaDB success.

`mysql_secure_installation` setting complete.

but I login `mysql -u root -p`

Insert Any password can login on linux root user.

(not root user has to enter the correct password)

---

This problem does not occur in `MariaDB v10.3`

but `MariaDB v10.4` Over version.

---

I think this situation is not security.

Can I find some solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the `Plugin` for the root user set to `unix_socket`.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select User,Host,Password,Plugin from mysql.user;
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| User          | Host      | Password                                  | Plugin      |
+---------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+-------------+
| root          | localhost | *XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX | unix_socket |
```

You can still turn it off:

`ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password;`

Documentation here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/

Comment: Thanks your answer. If I turn off the setting, can I use it as before?

Comment: It is set as above and it looks like mysql_native_password on the table, but it still happens to be logged in.

Comment: I tried query : `ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("password");` It works as intended. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing the plugin is not enough.
For me it worked with:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("password");
```